# Is there a `combineSoonest()` equivalent operator for RxJS that Emits all values as soon as any observable triggers?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have two forms on my page, and I want both of them to be valid before showing the save button. I was looking for something along the lines of:

```js
combineSoonest([
  this.nameForm.statusChanges,
  this.addressForm.statusChanges,
]).pipe(
  map(([nameStatus, addressStatus: [string, string]) => {
    const nameIsValid = nameStatus === undefined || nameStatus === 'VALID';
    const addressIsValid = addressStatus === undefined || addressStatus === 'VALID';

    return nameIsValid && addressIsValid;
  }),
).subscribe((isValid) => { this._showSaveButton(isValid); });
```

If I use the `combineLatest` operator, nothing will be emitted until both forms have been touched. Is there a `combineLatest`-like operator or option that allows me to emit even if one of the two combined observables has not emitted yet?

Comment: Does `RxJS.startWith()` help in changing this `nothing will be emitted until both forms have been touched`?
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `startWith` and `skip` to set this up.

```js
const name = this.nameForm.statusChanges.pipe(
  startWith(undefined)
)
const addressForm = his.addressForm.statusChanges.pipe(
  startWith(undefined)
)

combineLatest([name, addressForm]).pipe(
  // skip the first value which will be (undefined, undefined)
  skip(1),
  // from here, at least 1 value will be populated
  map(...),
).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Thanks @fujy and @Brandon, that is what I was looking for. I did not use the the `skip` because I needed the function to be executed with `false` initially.